# variable transformation in optimization

Tags: scales, optimization

I have an optimization problem with two sets of parameters, $x_i \in [0,1]$ and $y_k \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ where $i,k \in \{1...n\}$ are indices. One way to solve this problem is using constrained optimization by setting appropriate bounds on the parameters $x_i, y_k$.

I have a second idea, and that is to transform the variables using the following transformations. $$x_i = \frac{\left(1 + tanh\left(m_i\right)\right)}{2},\,\, y_i = tan^{-1}\left(n_i\right)$$ where $m_i,\, n_i$ are unconstrained parameters and $m_i,\, n_i \in [-\infty,\infty]$. I can now carry out the optimization wrt to $m_i,\, n_i$ and then re-transform the optimized parameters. Both these are 1-1 transformations.

Can someone point out the issues in variable transformation for optimization and what is the nature of functions that can be used. Also, if it leads to faster convergence?

Comment: If $y_k$ is close to $\pm \pi/2$, then $n_i$ will be very large in absolute value, and infinite if $y_k=\pm \pi/2$. Could you clarify why you want to transform the variables in the first place?

Comment: I want to use unconstrained optimization methods and compare how the constrained solution fares against unconstrained solution. My empirical experiment shows that unconstrained solution is much better than constrained solution

Answer (score 2):

This kind of transformation is not a very good idea in general.  Problems with this approach are discussed in many textbooks on nonlinear optimization.  For example, there's a discussion of several issues with this approach in the textbook Practical Optimization by Gill, Murray, and Wright.

In your particular case, the problem will become very ill conditioned (with a "flat bottom" of solutions that are all very close to optimal) if the optimal value of $y_{k}$ is near $\pi/2$.

Optimization methods for bounds constrained problems are robust, fast, and widely available.  There's really no reason that you have to use such a transformation.

Comment: My empirical experiment shows that unconstrained solution is always better  than constrained solution with these transformations. Why would that be the case. Even when I approach the boundaries, the solution is not exact but still better than a constrained solution

Comment: Also, if you are searching for solutions near the boundaries with parameters whose scale is unknown, there is not much one can do. I see that in this particular example with parameters in the following set {0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001}, the first two are estimated fine and the rest don't look good at all and similarly for the upper bound, but the solutions in the middle are very good. However, for the constrained case nothing is close.

Comment: Chances are that you're just using a bad solver for the bounds constrained problem....  You haven't told us what software you're using for the constrained solver, so it's hard to comment on that.

Comment: I am using R. I am using "L-BFGS-B". I have also tried nlminb